# AppBarButton lost function after changing it's Icon and Label in UWP C# Project

Tags: c#, function, xaml, button, uwp

AppBarButton lost function (doesn't execute it's code) after changing it's `Label` and `Icon` (the code work only for first click on button but doesn't work any more(after the change)) for example :

In this code `mediaPlayer.Pause();` works

```
private async void AppBarButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //PPB.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Play);
   //PPB.Label = "Preview";
   mediaPlayer.Pause(); //(i tested many other codes also)
}
```

but in this code `mediaPlayer.Pause();` not

```
private async void AppBarButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   PPB.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Play);
   PPB.Label = "Preview";
   mediaPlayer.Pause();
}
```

Comment: Maybe one of the lines changing the icon and label throw an exception?

Comment: I test the code, the second part works well, I could not reproduce your issue, Could share a [mcve].

Comment: this is my code : https://pastebin.com/jR1Gvge4

Comment: Please try update AppBar icon in the [UI-thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync).

Comment: I had tried this and unfortunately the same result

Comment: I created a sample with your segment code. but I can't reproduce your issue. Could try create a blank sample test this issue?